# Logstash bug when select by date from Postgres

Tags: postgresql, logstash

I have a PostgreSQL select statement in Logstash:

```
input {
    jdbc {        
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        # our query        
        statement => "SELECT * from schema1.data where date = '2018-04-14'"
    }
}
```

But when execute Logstash I got this bug:

> Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseError: Java::OrgLogstash::MissingConverterException: Missing Converter handling for full class name=org.postgresql.util.PGobject, simple name=PGobject>}

The problem is cannot cast to date. Does anyone know about this issue?